# I can't access to wordpress on xampp local host

Tags: php, wordpress

I find a problem in my site so I tried to access wordpress on xampp localhost
I recieved this message
{Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.2}
what's the problem and how can I fix it?
thanks

Comment: what is the url you requested in browser?

Comment: does your localhost/ actually works? meaning can you see xampp startup when you logon to localhost/ in your browser?

Comment: yes the local host is working

Comment: I can open the wordpress today but when I tried to update it I can't because of fatal error in the excution time

Comment: could you share the actual problem with some screenshot or something ? and also can you provide the URL you are trying to access